# How to test element in one Excel array is present in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a spreadsheet of time series data with a series of columns that mark the presence of certain events that took place.

Like so:

```
     A          B       C       D
1    Date       Event1  Event2  Event3
2    24/10/2016 T       NULL    NULL
3    31/10/2016 S       NULL    NULL
4    06/10/2016 NULL    NULL    NULL
5    20/10/2016 V       NULL    NULL
6    20/10/2016 T       S       V
7    01/12/2016 T       NULL    NULL
8    01/12/2016 S       T       NULL
9    29/11/2016 NULL    NULL    NULL
10   10/10/2016 T       NULL    NULL
```

I've then got a lookup table with a column of the events:

```
  A
1 T
2 S
3 V
```

What I'd like to do is create a new column in the time series to flag a single value, say 1, if at least one, but possibly more, of the events in the lookup has taken place.

What's an effective way of doing that?

UPDATE:

The problem is more complicated that there may be non-NULL event types that don't appear in my look up list and for which I wouldn't want to trigger the flag.

For instance if I had:

```
 9    29/11/2016    G       NULL    NULL
```

I would want to flag 0, but

```
 10   10/10/2016    G       T       NULL
```

I would want to flag 1.

Comment: Can the time series data contain events not in the lookup table? And your desired output is 1 if any event has occurred and 0 if no event has occurred?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify the point that there may be non-NULL event types that I wouldn't want to trigger the flag. The desired output is 1 if any event in the lookup has occured, and 0 if there hasn't. Moreover, I wouldn't want it triggered if an event not-listed occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it is sufficient to check if the Event1 column has one of the values in your lookup table.

For simplicity I will imply that both tables are in distinct sheets.

Hence, all you need to do is apply the VLOOKUP formula on the newly created column in the first sheet (let's simply call it "Flag").

The formula for the first cell (E2) should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:A, 1, false)
```

Just drag the same formula to the rest of the rows or double-click the bottom-right corner of this cell and you should be good to go.

This will also show you what the first event for that date is. If you only want a bit value (1/0), you can encase the formula in a simple IF.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

After the new info, the solution doesn't change much:

```
=IF(IsNA(VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:A, 1, false)), 0, 1) + IF(IsNA(VLOOKUP(C2, Sheet2!A:A, 1, false)), 0, 1) + IF(IsNA(VLOOKUP(D2, Sheet2!A:A, 1, false)), 0, 1)
```

This will even tell you how many of those values each row has.

Comment: I clearly didn't quite state the problem fully. There will sometimes be events in the time series that will appear that aren't null, but which I don't want to trigger the flag. And sometimes, there may be an event in Event1 that I don't want to flag for, but there is one in the Event2 slot. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, yes - i'm thinking up a solution

Comment: It does. That's great. Thank you.